# What are the consequences of different speeds of time interacting?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, gm-preparation, time

### How do different flows of time interact?

In a moment of improvisation, I created an extremely dangerous orb that is frozen in time by a spell. The next session will be in a couple of weeks because of Easter, and I realized that stopping time in a small space would have weird consequences. For example, what would happen if something were to go through the field separating the two times? And how do forces work on the time-bubble?

A more general form of my question is, how should I handle spaces with different flows of time, and how would they interact?

Comment: Ah, common sense, physics and d&d. Choose one!

Comment: Having a degree in physics, I warn you: don't choose physics for this. Go with common sense.

Comment: As a follow up, I will deal with the time bubble as an extremely delicate spell, like a soap bubble. If anything (big, not dust) were to cross the barrier, the time bubble would break. This also stops the spell from being exploitable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Different flows of time can effectively happen in your D&D game, across a portal between two planes or across the surface of a Planar Shepard character's bubble.

What really happens at the boundary is never specified by the rules. The most common interpretation you can find on forums is that a creature can either be at one side or the other, because this is used to make a lot of attacks from within an accelerated time bubble in most time shenanigans builds (they're completely OP and should be houseruled differently IMNSHO).

Otherwise, it seems like you need to decide how this works by yourself, and this usually means "think what should happen."
A time-stopped bubble is dangerous. If something enters it, it freezes in time, neither dying nor decaying. It's just moving infinitely slow.
Now, depending on what happens to items controlled by people out of the bubble (do they stop? If so, it's impossible to enter the bubble because what comes in contact with it can't move further) the other pcs might use tools to bring their unfortunate companion back. Or they might need to dispel the bubble.

Answer (score -2):

Quick and dirty answer: Just treat it like or some variation of the 9th level spell Time Stop. 
http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/timeStop.htm
Imagine the casting of Time Stop on an area rather than a character every round, effectively nothing occurs (I.E the standard combat round) outside of the bubble until the character chooses to move out of the area.

Comment: Could you please expand on how *time stop* is a solution to the challenge at hand? I'm not sure how it provides an example of something travelling into and then out of a bubble of different-speed time, for example.

Comment: While moving to a faster time zone can be modeled wit time stop (everybody outside the zone stops acting and you have some limitations on how they can interact with non-moving characters), slower time zones seem harder to model. Do you mean the character that's slower stops moving, but it's immune to direct attacks from the faster guys?